# Circular dependency in template class

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have a circular dependency simplified to the following:

```
// Bar.h
struct Bar {};

// Base.h
#include "Foo.h"
struct Bar;
struct Base {
    void func(std::shared_ptr<Foo<Bar>> foobar); // use methods of Foo in some way.
};

// Derived.h
#include "Base.h"
struct Derived : public Base {};

// Foo.h
#include "Derived.h"
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    void func(std::shared_ptr<Derived> d) {
        // use methods of Derived in some way.
    }
};
```

I can't simply forward declare `Foo` in `Base.h` as it is a template class, can't forward declare `Base` in `Derived.h` due to the polymorphism, and can't forward declare `Derived` in `Foo.h` because `Foo::func` uses members of `Derived`.

I've read before about separating template implementation from the declaration thought I'm unaware of best practices and unsure if it would work in this case.  The two, `Derived` and `Foo` are used widely throughout my program.

How can I resolve this dependency?

Comment: Why can't you forward-declare a class template?

Comment: As I understand it, I can't?  I was under the heavy assumption that the template had to be present in every translation unit it was used in and thus couldn't be forward declared.  Is that an invalid assumption?

Comment: "the template had to be present in every translation unit it was used in" yes (if you replace "use" with "instantiate"). " thus couldn't be forward declared" wrong. `template<class T> struct Foo;` is a well-formed forward-declaration.

Comment: Well well, we learn something new every day.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a function taking a `std::shared_ptr<type>` doesn't require a full definition of `type`, all that is needed is a (forward) declaration. This allows you to avoid `#include` of Derived.h (in Foo.h) and/or of Foo.h (in Base.h)

Comment: It's worth adding that what you said is true even if type is a template.  That's the part I didn't previously understand.

Comment: @vmrob Ah, didn't get that from your question. You could have broken the circularity in two places, only one requires to forward-declare a template class.

Comment: In trying to make my example as concise as possible, I made an error by only including the prototype of `Foo::func`.  The entire definition should have been there which would prevent a forward declaration of `Derived` in this case.

Comment: @vmrob No, the definition can be given later. Only the declarations are critical for avoiding circularity.

Answer (score 0):

Enable inline functions in classes referencing each other:

header A.h

```
struct B;
struct A { 
    void a() {}
    void f();
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
};
#include "A.tcc"
```

header A.tcc

```
#include B.h
inline void A::f() { b->b(); }
```

header B.h

```
struct A;
struct B { 
    void b() {}
    void f();
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
};
#include "B.tcc"
```

header B.tcc

```
#include A.h
inline void B::f() { a->a(); }
```

Please ensure all files have header guards!